# Unable to accept Pull Request Github because manual operations are required

Tags: git, merge, command-line-interface, pull-request

I have a private repo, and a collaborator has just made a new PR removing useless file (IDE config and build), but when i go to the PR page, I see the usual commits of the PR, then i see the message that there are merge conflicts, but I'm no able to solve this conflicts online as usual:

[image: PR]

The problem is that none of the link present on this image are clickable, i can hover them, but as soon as i click them, nothing changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the github interface and resolve the conflict on your local machine. I'm not saying the github interface for resolving conflicts is bad — on the contrary, for what it is, it's cool — but you don't need it.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but since no link are provided, can you please post the commands needed to do it locally (or link to a resource where is explained)...please

Comment: I _think_ you need to abort the merge on github. Now just switch to your local machine, `git fetch`, `git checkout master` (or whatever we're trying to merge into), `git merge origin/fix-untracked-files`, get the conflict, resolve it in the usual way, finish the merge, push (if I'm remembering correctly from when I've done this)